# How do you tell where an ODE has singularities?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For a linear differential equation, such as
$$y'' + p(x)\ y' + q(x)\ y=0$$
we know that the solutions may be singular at points where $p$ or $q$ have singularities, but must be regular everywhere else.

But if you have a nonlinear second-order ODE
$$y'' = F(x,y,y')$$
together with initial conditions $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, can you predict the values of $x$ where the solutions may be singular, by looking at $F$? Here $F$ is some given function that is Lipschitz in $y$ and $y'$, so that a unique solution exists in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: As long as you can find zeros of $1/F$, then yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no way to know a priori if the solution will have singularities, and if there are singularities, where they will be located. Consider the equation $y'=y^2$ with initial value $y(0)=y_0$. The solution is $y(x)=y_0/(1-y_0\,x)$. If $y_0=0$ the solution is regular; if $y_0\ne0$ it has a singularity at $x=1/y_0$. The existence and location of singularities will depend on the equation *and* on the initial values. Similar examples can be given for higher order equations.